# HTML/CSS (Bootstrap): Open hidden <input type="color"> color picker by clicking another HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to open a color picker from a hidden `<input type="color">` by clicking another HTML element, in this case a `<span>`. It seems to work most of the time on Firefox, but never on Chromium. Is there a cross-browser solution for this?

It is also important that the colorpicker appears in appropriate position to the hidden `<input type="color">` element, and not in top-left corner of HTML page as it shows up now. It also seems that clicking the right of the span, does not open the colorpicker.

```js
function changeColor() {
  var cp = document.getElementById("colorpicker")
  cp.click()
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown ms-5">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <span class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <label for="colorpicker">Change color</label>
        <input id="colorpicker" type="color" class="invisible">
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use correct semantic tags and everything will be easier

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <span class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <label for="colorpicker">Change color</label>
        <input id="colorpicker" type="color" class="invisible">
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```